# continuous function with precisely one point differentiability

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exists a real valued function which is everywhere continuous and differentiable at exactly one point on the real line?

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/298482/462).

Comment: @Andres: the function you refer to has many discontinuity points.

Comment: (@MartinArgerami Which is why this was a comment and not an answer.)

Answer (score 7):

You know that you can produce a function $f$ so that $f$ is continuous and differentiable nowhere.  Pick $a\in\mathbb{R}$; put $g(x) = (x - a)^2 f(x).$  The function $g$ is differentiable exactly at $a$ and nowhere else.

Comment: Why does it have to be squared?

Comment: Try using the definition of the derivative with and without the square.  You will see.

Comment: I still cant see the difference :/ excuse my stupidity :(

Comment: $(g(x) - g(0))/x = g(x)/x = f(x) \to f(0) $.  I guess the first power works. The square makes the derivative zero.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(t) $ be the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function), continuous everywhere and nowhere differentiable. Define
$$
g(t)=t^2f(t).
$$
Then $g$ is continuous everywhere and differentiable only at $t=0$.