# Prove function is differentiable at a point

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity

Prove that the function
$$f(x) =     \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      x^2, & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
      0, & x \in \mathbb{Q}^c \\
\end{array} 
\right.$$

is differentiable at $x = 0.$

I'm not sure how to calculate the limits for this function (the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is confusing me). Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Apply the squeeze lemma on the differential quotient. Find two functions it is always sandwiched between, which have limit zero.

Comment: Here's a very similar question (just subtract $x$): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298482/is-this-function-differentiable-at-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$\lim_{x\to 0,x\in \Bbb {Q}}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=0$$
and 
$$\lim_{x\to 0,x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=0.$$
Hence, $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

We need that

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 0$$ (having already done some simplification, and noting that the derivative must be zero if it exists, since the function is even).

Now, $$\frac{f(x)}{x} = \left\{\array{x,&x \in \mathbb{Q}\\0,&x \in \mathbb{Q}^c}\right.$$

Clearly, both the functions $g(x) = x$ and $h(x) = 0$ have the limit $0$ at $0$, so by what I guess you might have called the subset limit theorem, so does $\frac{f(x)}{x}$, so the limit is 0. In particular, the limit exists, so $f$ is differentiable at $0$.